# How to login and crawl a site using Mechanize

Tags: ruby, authentication, mechanize

I'm trying to use Mechanize to login and crawl a site.

For some reason, I can't seem to get the login function to work. Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new
a.get('https://jackthreads.com/')

form = a.page.form_with(:class => 'jt-form')
form.field_with(:name => "email").value = "email"
form.field_with(:name => "password21").value = "password"
page = a.submit(form, form.buttons.first)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action on the form is set to "`#`", so your submit is being ignored.  The POST call is actually being made to `https://www.jackthreads.com/login?method=ajax` via AJAX.  Perhaps if you update the form's action attribute with Mechanize before submitting, it will do the trick.

For what it's worth, I figured this out with the Chrome Web Inspector.  After seeing the value was set to "`#`", I went to the network tab, filtered by XHR, then tried submitting something.

Comment: So, Mechanize apparently does not provide support for JS. I tried changing the form's action to `https://www.jackthreads.com/login?method=ajax`, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Given that it's an ajax request, the submit won't properly take you to the logged in page, but you may in fact be logged in.  Have you tried requesting a different page?  I wonder if you strip off the "?method=ajax" from the URL if that would work.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Chrome's inspect panel is great but for https it won't tell you the whole story. For that you need to connect through a ssl proxy. I recommend fiddler or charles.