# How to find an embedded "a" tag

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I can't get an `a` tag in `p.user_info`:

```
<p class="user_info"> 
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="showSideView(this, 'login_id', 'user_name', 'ZmFubmlAaGFubWFpbC5uZXQ=', '');" title="[login_id]user_name">
        <img src='/cs2/data/member/fa/login_id.gif?dt=20130117095107' align='absmiddle' border='0'> of
    </a>
</p>
```

Using:

```
p_user_info = page.css("p.user_info")
puts p_user_info.css("a") # => []
puts p_user_info.css("a")[0] # => null
puts p_user_info.css("a").text # => ""
```

Is it possible to get `login_id`, `user_name` in `a` tag using Nokogiri?

---

I found a more important problem:

```
url = "http://clien.net/cs2/bbs/board.php?bo_table=park&wr_id=23895599"
html = open(url).read
puts html
# => ...
<p class="user_info"> <img src='/cs2/data/member/at/atlantis33.gif?dt=20130506110916' align='absmiddle' border='0'>님 </p>
...
```

I don't know why I can't get the `a` tag.

Comment: I solve this error. it's no login session.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "it is need login"

Comment: The question should be closed because it is off-topic since it can't be duplicated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby + Mechanize Login Stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614379/ruby-mechanize-login-stuck)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer my self. that `a` tag can see only after login. need `mechanize` library.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<eoh
<p class="user_info"> 
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="showSideView(this, 'login_id', 'user_name', 'ZmFubmlAaGFubWFpbC5uZXQ=', '');" title="[login_id]user_name">
        <img src='/cs2/data/member/fa/login_id.gif?dt=20130117095107' align='absmiddle' border='0'> of
    </a>
</p>
eoh

page = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
a = page.at_css("p.user_info a")
p a[:onclick].split(',')[1,2]
# => [" 'login_id'", " 'user_name'"]
p a[:onclick].split(',')[1,2].map { |x| x.gsub(/^[' ]+|[' ]+$/, '') }
# => ["login_id", "user_name"]
```

Comment: sorry, it's not nokogiri's problem...
open(url).read # => <p class="user_info"> <img src='/cs2/data/member/fa/fanni76.gif?dt=20130117095107' align='absmiddle' border='0'>님 </p>

Answer (score -1):

```
require 'nokogiri'                                                              

a =%{<p class="user_info">                                                      
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="showSideView(this, 'login_id', 'user_name', 'ZmFubmlAaGFubWFpbC5uZXQ=', '');" title="[login_id]user_name">
<img src='/cs2/data/member/fa/login_id.gif?dt=20130117095107' align='absmiddle' border='0'> of
</a>                                                            
</p>"}                                                          

html = Nokogiri::HTML(a)                                                        
link = html.at_css "a"                                                          
puts link.values[1].split[1]                                                    
puts link.values[1].split[2]
```

Comment: I find problem. open(url).read can't get **p.user_info a**. I think because ruby maybe.

Comment: This needs to demonstrate that it would actually retrieve the desired tag. The OP needed it to find "a" within a tag with a ".user_info" class. If there was a preceeding "a" the code would be wrong.